# In Gash Bell, why does Suzume fantasize that Kiyo has a long, pointed nose?

Tags: konjiki-no-gash-bell

In episode 112 of Konjiki no Gash Bell, just before skating with Kiyo, Suzume fantasizes that he has a long, pointed nose:

[image: Kiyo fantasy 1]

[image: Kiyo fantasy 2]

What is that all about?